# No sound with dual monitor

Tags: audio, multiple-monitors

When I had 1 monitor, the sound worked fine.

After installing 2nd monitor (new Zotac graphic card) for dual display I have no sound and no sound devices detected ().

Reinstalling sound drivers from CD doesn't help.

Do You have any idea how to restore the sound?

[image]

Comment: What's your default audio controller setting in windows? If it's set wrong, you won't get any sound.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you were using audio over HDMI or DisplayPort. Perhaps you have connected the display with speakers with a DVI cable. Make sure that your screen with speakers is connected with HDMI or DisplayPort cable. Then go to NVidia Desktop Manager and see if you can select audio output screen there. If you can't fix it there, go to Control Panel > Sound and try to pick a correct playback device

Answer (score 0):

Is the sound on-board i.e built in to the motherboard?
If so go into your BIOS settings and make sure that the internal speaker is enabled.
Seems to be a common thing with NVidia Graphics cards that they disable on board audio.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was able to fix it. As soon as I plugged in a second monitor using its DVI connection my sound output changed to the screen and as it had no speakers there is no sound. I just made the standars speakers the Default and all works well - screen attached and extended or not.